# Why is the master cost CPU about 0.2%，but the slave cost CPU about 60%?

Tags: redis, cpu-usage

When I use Redis，the master cost CPU about 0.2%, but the slave cost CPU is about 60%. My application only uses the master node，the slave nodes only have the active client including master and sentinel，in version 4.0.11.

I changed the config of RDB and AOF，trying to reduce the CPU cost. But the CPU cost for the slave node is still high. later，i restart the slave ，and cpu reduce to 0.2%，Why is that?